# Exception Handling - throwing an exception without any handlers

Tags: c++

```
void myterminate () 
{
   cout << "terminate handler called";
}

int main (void) 
{
   set_terminate (myterminate);
   
   throw;  // throwing an exception. So, terminate handler should be invoked 
           // as no one is handling this exception.    
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

> But After executing this code, the output is:
>
> > terminate handler called  +  "Debug Error!" dialog box appears.
>
> I am not sure why it is coming like this !!!! Please help.

Comment: I have executed this code on Visual studio 2008

Comment: So you're seeing a dialog box as a result of the exception being handed back to the O/S, and you're seeing your terminate function being called - that seems perfectly logical to me.   What were you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: @Ben:  I was only expecting the output as "terminator handler called" without any "Debug error" dialog box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the MSDN documentation for [set_terminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272914%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) the new handler function must call `exit()` or `abort()` will be called:

> The set_terminate function installs term_func as the function called by terminate. set_terminate is used with C++ exception handling and may be called at any point in your program before the exception is thrown. terminate calls abort by default. You can change this default by writing your own termination function and calling set_terminate with the name of your function as its argument. terminate calls the last function given as an argument to set_terminate. After performing any desired cleanup tasks, term_func should exit the program. If it does not exit (if it returns to its caller), abort is called.

For example:

```
void myterminate () 
{
   cout << "terminate handler called";
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Hi hmjd,  as per your comment, I can use either "exit(0)" or "abort()". But, if I am using abort(), it it still displaying error message.

Comment: @VikasChhipa No: use `exit()`. I did not state anywhere to use either. `abort()` is called if `exit()` is not. `abort()` will cause a "crash" of sorts: try calling `abort()` only in an small program to witness this.

Comment: I got confused because you said lke....Based on the MSDN documentation for set_terminate the new handler function must call exit() or abort() will be called:

So, when i am trying with abort() it still showing the same error.  Anyways, I got your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the requirments of the standard, a function used as a `terminate_handler` must meet the following requirement (ISO/IEC 14882:2011 18.8.3.1):

> *Required behavior*: A `terminate_handler` shall terminate execution of the program without returning
>   to the caller.

As your function doesn't meet this requirement you program has *undefined behaviour*. In order to see your custom diagnostic you should output a newline to `std::cout` (as this can be required on many platforms) and then terminate the program in some way, such as calling `std::abort`.

`std::abort` is used to signal an abnormal termination of the program so you can expect extra diagnostics to be reported to the user such as via the dialog box that you are seeing.

Note that using `std::exit` from a terminate handler is potentially dangerous as `std::terminate` might be called in response to an exceptional condition occurring in a function registered with `std::atexit` or `std:: at_quick_exit`. This would lead to a second attempt to call `std::exit`.

In summary, if you don't want an "abnormal" termination, you almost always need to catch exceptions that you throw.

Answer (score 1):

You have to exit program in your terminate handler. Add the following line to the handler and it will work:

```
exit(-1);
```

Comment: Hi spook,   When I am using "exit(-1); " inside my terminatte handler definition, I am not getting that annoying "Debug Error" dialog box.  But when I am using "abort();" instead of "exit(-1)", again the same error message appears.  Can you explain what is happening ??

Comment: @VikasChhipa: `abort()` can be used by a program to signal _abnormal_ termination of a program. It's completely reasonable for an implementation to signal this abnormal condition to the user in some way such as the error dialog box that you are seeing.

Comment: @charles :  OKAY SIR, got it :)